# Why people mostly wrap I18n.t method instead of delegating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I see many examples of

```
def t(*args)
  I18n.t(*args)
end
```

and very few

```
delegate :t, to: I18n
```

In my honest opinion second solution is semantically better. Why people tend to not use it?

Comment: I am gona go with "because they don't know about `delegate` method. "

Comment: are there any disadvantages of using delegate?

Comment: Have a look at `delegate` source code (yep, this is a method, not a keyword or anything). Under the hood it literally defines a method like yours. The only difference is that it takes some extra options to modify the method, but it is only executed once when module is laoded and the overhead is practically non-existent so in short - there is no measurable difference.

Comment: Also: it generates custom exception message, so it's easier to debug
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why people tend to not use it?

Well, one reason (as mentioned by @BroiSatse) is that people simply don't know about this technique.

From bytecode point of view, there is little difference. `delegate` generates roughly the same method, with a few additional checks for safety (`respond_to?`, etc.)

We, in our team, have this rule: `delegate` should be used to give a hint to *external* callers that methods are being forwarded to some other object. As a consequence, it should *not* be used just for "shortening" internal invocations of delegated methods. That is, if a method is not called from outside, don't use `delegate` on it, write the forwarding yourself.

So the choice is based on the message that we want to convey. And yes, we have both forms of delegation to `I18n.t` in our app :)

For example:

```
# use `delegate`, method is called from outside
class User
  has_one :address

  delegate :country, to: :address
end

<%= user.country %>


# only internal callers, do not use `delegate`
class Exporter
  # delegate :export, to: :handler 
  def call
    handler.export
  end

  private

  def handler
    return something_with_export_method
  end
end
```